# What does 'having higher density' means in terms of memory?

Tags: memory, dram

Please help me understand the following,

> Only one transistor (1T) is enough to build a dynamic memory cell.
>   Hence, DRAMs have higher densities and tend to be less expensive.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this context, "have higher densities" mean that the same number of transistors (or the same amount of die space) can store more bits.

Comment: Basically, more memory per area - it's an analog to the dictionary meaning of "density" as it pertains to physics.

Comment: "Higher density" actually means that more transistors can be packed into the same space, not that there are more bits stored per transformer (in general).

Comment: @CarlF: Not in this context. If you read the original quote, that meaning of "density" makes the quote senseless. (What does how many transistors are needed to build a cell have to do with how many transistors can be packed into the same space?)